# Most efficient way to store a GUID value in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, guid

Say, if I need to store non-repeating GUID values (something like `{AB50C41E-3814-4533-8F68-A691B4DA9043}`) in the SQL Server database, what is the most efficient way to define the column to store it? (i.e. as string, a blob, or convert it into a 16-byte integer.)

PS. The column must be defined as an INDEX and be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- Use the [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942(SQL.90).aspx) data type which is designed for GUIDs
  For example, they will [sort like GUIDs should](http://web.archive.org/web/20190402004032/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)
- [Create a UNIQUE index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(SQL.90).aspx) on it (more flexible than a unique constraint

Note, these are 2 separate steps

Comment: Yeah, but uniqueidentifier is specific for SQL Server 2008. Can I use it in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Oh, cool. You must have changed the link because I swear it said "SQL Server 2008" there a minute earlier :) So, thanks, that will do!

Comment: The link "sort like GUIDs should" is a dead link.

Answer (score 12):

You can use uniqueidentifier datatype